# Rails 4.1.0 elasticsearch Tire association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, tire

I'm getting an error with my (re)Tire gem integration after upgrading to Rails 4.1.0
Before i was running This code in my `Product Model` with Rails 4.0.4 :

```
def self.search(params)
  tire.search( load:{:include => [:user, :tags]}, match_all: {}, page: params[:page], per_page: 12) do
    sort do
        by :created_at, 'desc'
        end
    query do
      boolean do
        must { string params[:query], default_operator: "AND" } 
        must { term :online, true }
        must_not { string 'location:Undefined' }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It was working fine, but now ActiveRecord throw me this error :

```
Couldn't find all Products with 'id': (1118, 1036, {:include=>[:user, :tags]}) (found 2 results, but was looking for 3)
```

My question is how can i do to load associated models with Tire gem?
is `load:{:include => [:user, :tags]` correct?

Thanks in advance JD.

Answer (score 0):

Tire performs the load using `klass.find(ids, @options[:load])`. This find behavious has been deprecated for a while but supported via a gem [activerecord-deprecated_finders](https://rubygems.org/gems/activerecord-deprecated_finders). Rails 4.1.0 removed the default dependency on that gem.

You should be able to include the gem in your Gemfile yourself to restore the behaviour:

```
gem 'activerecord-deprecated_finders'
```

Comment: Not working with gem 'activerecord-deprecated_finders'

Comment: In exactly the same way? After a `bundle install`?